# PHP - query to variable - not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having some issues with my SQL Query. I am trying to run an sql query that saves the output into a variable and then print the variable in a different section of code:

Query:

```
$sql = "select Count(distinct `Customer Name`) as columnNameCount from allservers";
$result = mysqli_query($DBcon, $sql);
```

Display variable:

```
<h3 align="center"><?php echo $resultarr;?></h3>
```

Error message:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: $resultarr ? Where is that Variable ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "select Count(distinct `Customer Name`) as columnNameCount from allservers";
$result = mysqli_query($DBcon, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
?>
<h3 align="center"><?php echo $row[0];?></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember: Mysqli_query() return an **Object Resourse** to your variable $result! Not a String!

*You can't directly use it as $result variable!*
If you have multiple results, you can loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    echo $row['some_row'];
```

else you have to fetch as row and display according to index:

```
$row = $result->fetch_row(); 
echo $row[0]; // $row[index]
```

[Read The Documentaion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)